# Strech .gif images in a win32 windows program

Tags: image, winapi, gif

I am making an application, where I am trying to resize a .gif animation image, which i am showing in another window inside the main window. 
As of now now I am using the SetWindowPos function present in windows.h. This function, simply resizes the window, but not the image.

Please help me out in my problem. I want to resize a .gif animation image using win32 programming in language C++.

Comment: What window are you shoing the GIF in? Is it a standard control or a custom one you've made? What's doing the animation?

Comment: I am making a custom window with no taskbar and scrollbars theme, and there is separate piece of code responsible for loading and animating the gif. I picked most part of my code from this tutorial - www.cplusplus.com/files/wingif.zip.